# Core dumped in OpenCV matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I do not understand why I am getting `core dumped` here:

```
int nrows = 480, ncols = 640;
cv::Mat m3_8u;
// Create a variable of type cv::Mat* named m3_8u which has three channels with a
// depth of 8bit per channel. Then, set the first channel to 255 and display the result.
m3_8u.create(nrows, ncols, CV_8UC3);
for (int i=0; i<nrows; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<ncols; j++){
       m3_8u.at<cv::Vec3f>(i,j)[0] = 255;
    }
}
```

I want to change all the values from the first color dimension.

Comment: The `Mat` has datatype of `CV_8UC3` (3x8 bit integers per pixel), but you access it as `cv::Vec3f` (3x32bit floats per pixel). That means you eventually start accessing past the end of the allocated buffer. Plus you read out garbage as well.

Comment: To add to what @DanMašek said, you want to use cv::Vec3B. Vec3f says that the data comes in three floats (four bytes each). Vec3b says that the data comes in 3 uchar (one byte each) which is what you are using as specified by CV_8UC3.